# Invalid integer error?

Tags: apex, error-messages

I am having the strangest error attempting to take a string from a custom setting and make it into an integer array. I am new at this but I cant wrap my head around why this is happening or how to fix it. The error is coming from the unsubgroup section. It's assigning the second string in the list somewhere not really sure where or how or why.

```
public class campdata {
//Campiagn Maker vars
public integer  key {get; set;}
public integer sndrid {get; set;}
public list<integer> lids = new list<integer>();
public list<integer> segids = new list<integer>();
public list<integer> sgi = new list<integer>();
public list<string> tempname = new list<string>();
list<string> name = new list<string>{'shay', 'austin'};

    public void sorts(){
            system.debug(sgi);

    for(integer i=0; i <= 1; i++){
     string placeholder = name[i];
     sendgridsettings__c sgs = sendgridsettings__c.getInstance(placeholder);
                         //Campaign Names
                         string campstring = sgs.campaign_names__c; system.debug(campstring);
                            tempname = campstring.split(','); system.debug('tempname@@@@@ '+tempname);

                         //unsub group ids
                         string unsubstring = sgs.unsubgroup__c;
                            List<string> unsub = unsubstring.split(',');
                                for(string usb :unsub)
                                { system.debug(usb+'usb');
                                    integer j = integer.valueOf(usb); system.debug(j+' =jjjj@@@@@@@@@'); system.debug('sgi&&&'+sgi);

                                    sgi.add(j);
                                    system.debug('sgi #@#@#@#   '+sgi);
                                }

                         // segment id 
                         string segstring = sgs.segment_id__c;
                            List<String> segs = segstring.split(',');
                                for(String str :segs)
                                {   integer k = Integer.valueOf(str);

                                    segids.add(k); 
                                    system.debug('segids #@#@#@#   '+segids);
                                }  

        for(integer i2=0; i2<11; i++){
           //sender id retrieved from custom setting
             sndrid = integer.valueof(sgs.Sender__c);
            // list id 
             integer lid  = integer.valueof(sgs.list_id__c); 
system.debug('lid@@@@@@'+ lid);
                    lids.add(lid);


                    if(i2<=5 && i!=1){
                      key = 0;
                     }
                    if(i2>=6 && i==1){
                      key = 1;
                    }
            integer senderid = sndrid;
            integer listid = lids[i];
            integer segmentid = segids[i2];
            integer unsubgroupid = sgi[key];
            string campaignname = tempname[i2];

    SendGrid_CampaignMaker SGCM = new SendGrid_campaignMaker();
    SGCM.builder(senderid, listid, segmentid, unsubgroupid, campaignname);
      }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the error message and what is the specific line where it occurs?

Comment: 22:42:01:034 FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Invalid integer:  1148341 on line 36

Comment: Which is line 36?  Please edit your original post to call out that line by itself.

Comment: It's in the Segment Id section: integer k = Integer.valueOf(str.trim());

Comment: Does the setting actually have a list of valid integers?

Comment: properly formatting/indenting your code will get more responses

Comment: @RogerMorris, Check for spaces & remove them before the conversion. I do not see any trimming operation in your code even though you mentioned in the comments. Print and debug the custom settings value before the operation.